# Is there a voice authentication library?

Tags: authentication, speech-recognition

Does anyone know if there's a good voice authentication library available? Or do I need to find a good voice recognition library and build from there?

Comment: come on, tag this as "passport"!

Comment: http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0105435/quotes - "My voice is my passport. Verify me."

Comment: http://mistral.univ-avignon.fr/

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/improved-mistral/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are several open source packages implementing speaker recognition. For example Mistral

http://mistral.univ-avignon.fr/

There are clones of mistral too

http://code.google.com/p/improved-mistral/

Answer (score 8):

Speech Recognition is usually quite different from voice authentication (often called voice biometrics). Here is a good overview document - http://www.sans.org/reading_room/whitepapers/authentication/exploration-voice-biometrics_1436 says:

> There are consultant companies such as J. Markowitz, Consultants who
>   rank voice vendor software. These reports are often available for
>   purchase online. One vendor’s implementation may be more suitable than
>   another depending on the use case. Nuance (www.nuance.com) and Vocent
>   (www.vocent.com) are two vendors who provide voice authentication
>   solutions and who came up repeatedly in the research for the “Current
>   Applications” section of this paper. Nuance has been rated the top
>   voice authentication technology vendor by Celent Communications.12
>   Nuance claims a 96% or higher accuracy rate for speech recognition13,
>   and Nuance’s Verifier product claims a “high” accuracy rate.

That is a good overview, but it is a little out of date. Look around for others such as:

- http://www.persay.com/technology-voice-biometrics.asp
- http://www.voxeo.com/biometrics/home.jsp
- http://www.nuance.com/landing-pages/enterprise/voice-biometrics/default.asp
- http://www.angel.com/products/voice-biometrics.php
- http://www.voicevault.com/voicevault-enterprise/