# shazam for voice recognition on iphone

Tags: ios

I am trying to build an app that allows the user to record individual people speaking, and then save the recordings on the device and tag each record with the name of the person who spoke. Then there is the detection mode, in which i record someone and can tell whats his name if he is in the local database.

First of all - is this possible at all? I am very new to iOS development and not so familiar with the available APIs.

More importantly, which API should I use (ideally free) to correlate between the incoming voice and the records I have in the local db? This should behave something like Shazam, but much more simple since the database I am looking for a match against is much smaller.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7269935/is-there-a-voice-authentication-library

Comment: Well, not exactly, no - but you still want to find a speaker recognition/authentication library ("voice recognition" is usually understood to mean speech-to-text), and some of those listed in that thread may help you (in particular, http://code.google.com/p/improved-mistral). This is likely to be non-trivial - you'll need to drive the audio hardware to record things and plumb in someone else's C library to do the recognition. If you're very new to iOS development then I'd start with something easier. ;-)

Comment: and what do you consider as something easier? :)

Answer (score 4):

If you're new to iOS development, I'd start with the core app to record the audio and let people manually choose a profile/name to attach it to and worry about the speaker recognition part later.

You obviously have two options for the recognition side of things: You can either tie in someone else's speech authentication/speaker recognition library (which will probably be in C or C++), or you can try to write your own.

How many people are going to use your app? You might be able to create something basic yourself: If it's the difference between a man and a woman you could probably figure that out by doing an FFT spectral analysis of the audio and figure out where the frequency peaks are. Obviously the frequencies used to enunciate different phonemes are going to vary somewhat, so solving the general case for two people who sound fairly similar is probably hard. You'll need to train the system with a bunch of text and build some kind of model of frequency distributions. You could try to do clustering or something, but you're going to run into a fair bit of maths fairly quickly ([gaussian mixture models](http://speech.ee.ntu.edu.tw/previous_version/Speaker%20Verification%20Using%20Adapted%20Gaussain%20Mixture%20Models.pdf), et al). There are libraries/projects that'll do this. You might be able to port this from matlab, for example: https://github.com/codyaray/speaker-recognition

If you want to take something off-the-shelf, I'd go with a straight C library like mistral, as it should be relatively easy to call into from Objective-C.

The [SpeakHere](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SpeakHere/Introduction/Intro.html) sample code should get you started for audio recording and playback.

Also, it may well take longer for the user to train your app to recognise them than it's worth in time-saving from just picking their name from a list. Unless you're intending their voice to be some kind of security passport type thing, it might just not be worth bothering with.

Comment: The ability to recognize who is speaking from the list of records is critical for me. I know that I can play with FFT, etc, but eventually I'll need to perform cross correlations to be able to detect who is speaking. My plan is to record each person that gets into the DB for about 30 seconds so I'll have enough training data. The thing is that I dont want to invent the wheel with this engine - I have done a bunch of that in matlab in the past, but right now, I am just looking for a simple library, that ideally would get one string and the DB and will return "scores" for each person in the DB.