# Voice Authentication HTML5

Tags: html, authentication, voice-recognition

I have heard about using voice recognition to authenticate users. I wanted to use it in an HTML5 program immediately, but no matter how many Google searches I did, I  couldn't figure out how to program it. Could anyone please help me? **I have not fabricated any code yet!**

Comment: Do you have a link or a starter point?

Comment: @CaioTarifa: I did not start programming it yet; I would like to get a general idea about what to do first.

Comment: http://shapeshed.com/html5-speech-recognition-api/

Comment: @NooBskie: This looks good for voice _recognition_, but I am looking for a secretive voice _authentication_, or voice biometrics system, and as the article said, this way of doing it is not very high on security. Also, I am trying to find something that is cross-platform compatible and works on most browsers, and as far as I can tell, this only works on Chrome. **I am trying to use ir for logging in to a website.** Is there something rhat works with PHP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Authentication requires that the server shares a secret with the user. This is often an asymmetric secret where one side can only verify, and not reproduce the other side.

In the case of voice authentication, this typically is represented as a cryptographic (hard to reverse engineer) fuzzy (not an exact match - you'll never sound exactly the same) hash (numeric representation) of a spoken passphrase. This offers stronger authentication over a pure password, because in addition to knowing the password you need to know the voice. You may find resources for text-to-speech APIs, but using these will not give you any additional security over a password approach.

In the end you're going to need to do the authentication on the server, so if you find a good library to do your hashing, you could stream the sound bytes to the server (lots of ways to do this) and do your hashing & authentication server side.

This isn't a step-by-step how-to answer, but coming up with a complete design will depend a lot on other requirements of the system. Search for solutions under "voice biometrics", such as [Is there a voice authentication library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7269935/is-there-a-voice-authentication-library)

Comment: Thanks Tim, _very_ good answer, though I didn't understand how to use Mistral.